# AQC definition modifications costs and pay-offs

Tags: annealing, adiabatic-model, stoquatic-matrices

I was wondering if one can think of a more general relation between alleviating conditions for the state in which the evolution takes palce in AQC paradigm and constraining the structure of the Hamiltonian. 
To illustrate: if we constrain ourselves to a stoquastic Hamiltonian but allow for evolution in an excited state, such setup is as poewrful as original AQC. An example would be from Jordan, Gosset, and Love work https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4755 mentioned in https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04471

> Our definition of StoqAQC (Definition 6) stipulates that the
> computation must proceed in the ground state. It turns out that
> if this condition is relaxed, computation with stoquastic
> Hamiltonians is as powerful as AQC, i.e., it is universal.
> Here we review a construction by Jordan, Gosset, and Love
> (2010) of a 3-local stoquastic Hamiltonian that, by allowing
> for excited state evolution, is both QMA complete and
> universal for AQC.

Is there any point to look at such case in a more general way and look for relations between the structure of the Hamiltonian and the type of state/states used in evolution of the system?